# Show image after page is loaded in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have view (user's profile) where i have browse button to set profile picture, one image control to show preview, text box to add for user information, label to show user's information and submit button to add all data in database. When login is successfully done, and when user selects this page, user's profile picture and information i want to display in image and label control.
When user selects image using browse button, i want to show that preview image in my image control. That part works fine, but when pages is loaded for the first time, i want to show user's profile picture and user's information from the database. Also i want to show the user's information in label. My image and text, both i want to add from control. So i have created the method in control which takes user's id as an argument, fetches content from database. but can any one tell me how i display this content in my controls (image and label). below is the sample code what i have done :

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ToShowUserInfo(int UserId)
        {
            MyEntity me = new MyEntity ();
            //pass login user's id in below query, for sample "1" is passed
            UserPersonalInfo km = me .UserPersonalInfoes.ToList().Where(a => a.UPI_UserId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            FileContentResult fcr = ConvertFromBytes(km.UPI_ProfilePicture);

            return fcr;
        }
```

View :

```
<img id="preview" src="@Url.Action("ToShowUserInfo", "Account", new { UserId = 1 })" height=100 width=200 />
```

In controller i am getting information from database i can figure out how i can show it on view on user's request on page i.e. when page is loaded for the first time after login in done

Comment: I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: I am asking how do i load image and information on my view from controller on page load

Comment: Is your image not showing? You need to add a label to your view for the other information and show the label information form the model your view is using.

Comment: Nah, my image is not showing, and first i want to show image, i will show information afterwards once image is shown properly.

Comment: You should use a javascript image preloading library, or you can write it on your own. ASP.NET creates content, if you want to modify how to render it. use javascript.

Comment: can't i load it without javascript? when user selects image using browse button, at that time i am showing preview image using javascript, but without javascript i cant show image for the first time? and also can you tell me how do i show image using javascript for the first time as my image is going to come from controller

Comment: when you run the page in your webbrowser check the network tab of the developer panel for error messages. What is the html markup of your image tag? What is the src attribute set to. What happens if you browse directly to the value in the source attribute?